# Strange windows boot problem - My computer won't boot from hard disk

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot

Until yesterday, I had windows XP installed on my computer. After installing the OS, and setting the BIOS to boot from the hard-disk first, I discovered a strange problem - the OS wasn't booted and the only way I could get it to load was to insert a windows installation disk, enter repair mode, do "fixboot" and restart. The problem only occured when the computer was booted after shut-down. If I only restarted it, everything worked fine.
Yesterday, I upgraded my XP to win7 and the problem persists. 
I tried the same "trick" I did with XP to get it to load, by entering repair and doing "bootrec /fixmbr" and "bootrec /fixboot" but that didn't work (and when I run "scanos" it didn't find any windows installations).
Eventually, I got it to load by changing the settings in the BIOS to boot from CD first and HD second, removing the installation disk from the drive, letting it fail to boot from CD and then re-insert the disk.
Anyone has any idea what may be the cause or how can I investigate this issue?

Thanks!
Marina

Answer (score -1):

check the partition table and make 1st partition bootable,
actually bootrec /fixmbr should work, eventually its not working then at least try setting 1st partition as bootable flag.